# how to override collection variable from newman cli? --env-var did not seem to work

Tags: postman-newman

I need to override the collection variable from command line using --env-var(there is no --collection-var in options) but seems not working, I think because collection variable is narrow than the environment so won't work. I cannot change the collection variable in the source, or give the new name of this variable, so how to override?